# What are some good examples of JQuery using JSONP talking to .net?

Tags: .net, jquery, jsonp

As the question says, what are some good examples (or just examples really), of Jquery using JSONP to talk to a .net page or webservice?

I'm attempting to write a page which uses JQuery to call another website (Thus I need to use JSONP) which hosts the webservice/webpage (either is fine), and I can't find a good example of this.

Comment: Here is a really good example of how to jsonp with asp.net mvc.
http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSONP is just json wrapped inside a js method. jQuery provides the method name as a callback parameter on the querystring which the jsonp endpoint must then take and wrap the json in then send the response back. The server side language really is irrelevant.

[JSONP with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898.aspx)

[Good screencast](http://www.vimeo.com/1535196)

& a few articles below

[Rick Strahl has a blog post on it](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/107136.aspx)
[Another](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2007/09/28/implement-jsonp-in-your-asp-net-application.aspx)