# How does crossdomain data access work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, json

I'm using JQuery to make a JSON request to access data on a private server. I've noticed however that I get this message when attempting to access the data:

> Security Error: Content at xxxxxxx may
>   not load data from xxxxxxx.

Looking at the JQuery reference I see it's accessing: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?

I'm wondering how Flickr is able to deliver data without an error message popping up as such. Initial investigation has showed me that it's actually on the server end, it adds some sort of callback function.

Basically the question is, how exactly does this work and how do I implement it on webservices I've created on the server I plan to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use JSONP.  @redsquare posted a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448879/what-are-some-good-examples-of-jquery-using-jsonp-talking-to-net) with links to some excellent articles.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to do it is to create a http handler on hte current server that actually gets the request server side from the other server and than call that handler locally.